# Write event log on remote machine using specific credentials

Tags: c#, .net, impersonation, event-log

I've been looking for a way to write event logs on a remote machine using specific credentials. This will be used for auditing the use of my application within the domain (the application does various server tasks but can be run from any PC in the domain). As a requirement, the program needs to be able to create event logs on a specified server with specified credentials, from any PC on the domain or a PC that is VPN'd into the domain.

I currently have the below code to create an event log:

```
EventLog evntlog = new EventLog("Application");
evntlog.MachineName = "192.168.0.5";
evntlog.Source = "Application";
evntlog.WriteEntry("Test Log.", EventLogEntryType.Information, 11573);
```

The above `EventLog` namespace doesn't seem to allow specifying the credentials for the connection/remote machine.
Meanwhile the `EventLogSession`/`EventLogReader` does, as per below for retrieving the event logs (this works perfectly for my test scenario):

```
string query = "*[System/EventID=11573]";
EventLogSession session = new EventLogSession("192.168.0.5", domain, userName, userPass, SessionAuthentication.Default);
EventLogQuery evntquery = new EventLogQuery("Application", PathType.LogName, query);
evntquery.Session = session;
EventLogReader logReader = new EventLogReader(evntquery);
```

I've tried to find a way to write entries similar to the way they are read above but can't seem to find an equivalent (`EventLog` does not support a `Session`). Impersonation is also not possible as the program will be pointing to a different domain entirely, without any trust between them.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of event log you should think of something simpler. Write all the event data in a log file using some logging framework such as serilog or log4net. These can write logs to log files and also to the database. You can actually write event data from all the instances of the application to one central database and the auditing program can read the data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the answer you are looking for, but this is abdolutelly not the way to achieve this. Logs are bound to their context logically, and even if you are able to log on remote machine, you get a mess.

Without trust your only option is to start some kind of proxy that will accept your events over network and store them for you. But why doing this? 'syslog' provides this for ages, and even windows has its own infrastructure for managing log centralisation. Read this: https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/centralizing-windows-logs/ I saw posts about this stating that this is working also accross independent domains, but you might need some extra work to configure it.

Comment: I might need to clarify the test scenario. The idea is that the program when used can create an event log for auditing purposes, the program may be used on any PC within the domain or PC's that are using a VPN to the domains network. This means that the retrieval of Event Logs works fine but there's no option for specifying credentials when creating the logs.